# Sharing connections on a circuit-switched network possible?

Tags: networking, router, internet, packet, connection-sharing

Is it possible to somehow share a circuit-switched connection? For example, could multiple computers be connected to a router which is connected to a circuit-switched network?

Comment: Circuit switched?  As in voice circuits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  A more detailed answer isn't possible without more details.

If its an IP network, and you have your computers attached to your router with ethernet, and your router knows how to speak IP over the circuit switched network, your multiple computers won't know the difference.

Comment: I thought IP only works in packet-switched networks.

Comment: There are data circuit switched networks.  You could start at the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_switching an read on from there.

Comment: ATM and Frame Relay is, typically, circuit-switched (well, it's arguable that they're label-switched, but...). MPLS is pretty close to being circuit-swicthed.